# Contradiction between accuracy obtained from my pretrained conv base network and pretrained conv base network in Deep Learning with Python

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pre-training

I trained a pretrained convnet model on the cats and dogs dataset and the following are the accuracies obtained:

1. Freezed Conv Base ~ 90%
2. Unfreezed Conv Base ~ 96%

However this is in contradiction to the accuracies listed in the book:

1. Freezed Conv Base ~ 96%
2. Unfreezed Conv Base ~ 90%
   The results are exactly opposite. What am I missing or the book's results are incorrect?
   Btw. I am using Keras 2.2.4.

Comment: If you unfreeze the pertained layers, the network has chance to fine-tune to your data, so you'd usually expect *better* performance after unfreezing and re-training it.

Comment: Yeah..But the book says the opposite..It says that due to random initialization of the following Dense classifier, higher updates to the parameters of the conv base can cause the conv to deviate from the optimum ones...

Comment: It depends on many things, I'd need to refer to the book to say more.